# How to dequeue a message automatically by getting a notification on application side

Tags: c++, oracle, stored-procedures, oracle10g, oracle11g

If there is some data falls in the queue table.How to dequeue a message automatically by getting a notification in my application side .

Below is the link i am following for enqueuing the message into a queue table, its happening successfully.

http://www.oratechinfo.co.uk/aq.html

I can see the message i enqueued in the queue table with the following query at the scheduled time.

```
 select user_data from queue_table;
```

And below is the link to C++ code to dequeue the message.With the below c++ code i am able to dequeue the data manually in my application side.But i want a method to dequeue automatically by getting a notification and start to dequeue automatically.Please give me a hand and make it clear.

http://docs.oracle.com/cd/A83908_02/NT816EE/DOC/nt.816/a99999/o4c00069.htm

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if this is possible in C, but from PL/SQL, you would create a callback procedure with the following signature.

```
CREATE PROCEDURE demo_queue_callback_procedure(
                 context  RAW,
                 reginfo  SYS.AQ$_REG_INFO,
                 descr    SYS.AQ$_DESCRIPTOR,
                 payload  RAW,
                 payloadl NUMBER
                 ) AS

   r_dequeue_options    DBMS_AQ.DEQUEUE_OPTIONS_T;
  r_message_properties DBMS_AQ.MESSAGE_PROPERTIES_T;
  v_message_handle     RAW(16);
  o_payload            demo_queue_payload_type;
```

BEGIN

```
  r_dequeue_options.msgid := descr.msg_id;
  r_dequeue_options.consumer_name := descr.consumer_name;

  DBMS_AQ.DEQUEUE(
     queue_name         => descr.queue_name,
     dequeue_options    => r_dequeue_options,
     message_properties => r_message_properties,
     payload            => o_payload,
     msgid              => v_message_handle
     );

    -- Do something with the payload received.  Must commit to get message out of table.

       COMMIT;
```

END;
   /

--  create a subscriber, and register your callback procedure

```
   DBMS_AQADM.ADD_SUBSCRIBER (
      queue_name => 'demo_queue',
      subscriber => SYS.AQ$_AGENT(
                       'demo_queue_subscriber',
                       NULL,
                       NULL )
      );

   DBMS_AQ.REGISTER (
      SYS.AQ$_REG_INFO_LIST(
         SYS.AQ$_REG_INFO(
            'DEMO_QUEUE:DEMO_QUEUE_SUBSCRIBER',
            DBMS_AQ.NAMESPACE_AQ,
            'plsql://DEMO_QUEUE_CALLBACK_PROCEDURE',
            HEXTORAW('FF')
            )
         ),
      1
      );
```

You would have to change the above to read from the error queue, but I think concept is the same.

Comment: I am not getting how in this way it will dequeue automatically if something in the queue?

Comment: Because you are registering the stored procedure as a handler by calling DBMS_AQ.Register.  This procedure will then be called each time a message is in the queue.  Please see these links: [link](http://www.oratechinfo.co.uk/aq.html)  [link](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B12037_01/appdev.101/b10802/d_aq.htm)